# jQuery & boostrap: What does fn[NAME] do?

Tags: jquery

I am going through the javascript code for bootstrap.

In [modal.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js) I see:

```
  $.fn[NAME]             = Modal._jQueryInterface
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Modal
```

Where `NAME` is `'modal'`
What does `$.fn[NAME]` do? I know what plain `$.fn` is, not sure about the `[NAME]` and thee `.Contractor`.

Comment: is  same as doing `$.fn.modal = Modal._jQueryInterface`. Creates a plugin function to allow you to do `$(selector).modal()`

Comment: :D thanks!! Do you want to add it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is  same as doing `$.fn.modal = Modal._jQueryInterface` but using `[]` notation instead of dot notation

Creates a plugin function to allow you to do `$(selector).modal()`